# Why arguments in braces do not expand in this case?

Tags: bash, command-line, brace-expansion

For example, I want to put some file names inside braces for expansion like this:

```bsh
$ ls
blue_texture  blue_waves  green_light
$ ls -m | tr -d ' \n'
blue_texture,blue_waves,green_light 
$ echo foo/bar/{`ls -m | tr -d ' \n'`}
foo/bar/{blue_texture,blue_waves,green_light}
```

My question why doesn't brace expansion work here? I expected it to work as following:

```bsh
$ echo foo/bar/{blue_texture,blue_waves,green_light}
foo/bar/blue_texture foo/bar/blue_waves foo/bar/green_light
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason this does not work is because `bash` performs brace expansion *before* command substitution (the [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions) has some information about this). The substitution is not performed until after the brace expansion already occurred.

The only way you could do this is by using `eval`, but **do not** do that in this case, as you will allow arbitrary command execution.

Instead you have to seek some other method. This should produce the output you seek:

```
for file in *; do
    printf '%s ' "foo/bar/$file"
done; echo
```

Answer (score 2):

With zsh:

```
files=(*)
echo foo/bar/$^l
```

(`${^array}` turns on brace-expansion style expansion for the array).

Or:

```
echo ./*(:s:.:foo/bar:)
```

Applies a history-expansion style substitution to filename expansion.

With any shell

```
printf 'foo/bar/%s\n' *
```

Or:

```
set -- *
for i do
  set -- "$@" "foo/bar/$i"
  shift
done
echo "$@"
```

(note that `echo` in most shells performs some transformations on the arguments it gets so is better avoided for arbitrary input).